# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (request)

Tags: python, request, typeerror

```
import requests

with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as file:
 for line in file:
  for word in line.split():
   link = requests.get(https://google.com)
   word = "balloon"
   if word in link.text():
    print("nice word!")
   else:
    print("bad word!")
```

Whenever I try this code the following error pops up:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Does anyone know what I did wrong? If so, please help me out <3

Comment: Doesn't that error come with more information?

Answer (score 2):

```
if word in link.text():
```

`.text` is a plain attribute, not a function call. Don't put parentheses at the end.

Comment: Does this check if word exists in the entire source code of the website? because I dont think it is doing that or am I just blind?

Comment: It checks for the word in the entire text content of the fetched url.

Comment: but it isnt checking class names am i right? is there any way of making this possible?

Comment: It checks the entire text content of the url, which includes CSS class names.  So yes, it is checking class names (and a lot of other things too).  Did you want to _only_ check class names?

Comment: Yeah, I would only want it to check for class names

Comment: Instead of checking for just the word `balloon`, you could check for the HTML fragment `class="balloon"`.  But there might be some cases where that won't work.

Comment: I'll try figuring it out. Thanks for the help my friend! <3 @John Gordon